# Firebase Cloud Functions - The default firebase app doe not exist

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Im getting this error in my firebase cloud functions logs.

[image]

I want to delete a user using `admin.auth().deleteUser(req.body.uid).then().catch()`

I initialized the `firebase-admin` like :

```
admin.initializeApp({
    ...functions.config().firebase,
    databaseAuthVariableOverride: { uid: 'some-worker-id' }
}, 'some-name')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing the admin SDK with the name 'some-name'.  That's by definition *not* the default instance.  Don't give it a name, and you will be initializing the default instance.  If you don't need multiple admin instances to connect to multiple projects, then don't give it a name and take the default.

Comment: But I need multiple admin instances.

Comment: In that case, update your question to explain *why* you need multiple instances and make sure your code includes how you initialize and use all instances.